# After system upgrade, blank screen with cursor flashing and won't load GUI (Nvidia driver problem)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, upgrade, system

thank you in advance for your help. I know there are many threads about similar topics to this, but none have worked, trust me I have tried them all!

Ubuntu prompted a system update, including Nvidia drivers, through the GUI, I clicked accept and it updated in the OS. After the update, I could not view images, with the error message:

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_glib_script_to_script`

The update prompted a restart, so I did, hoping it would fix it. After that, it would not start, and i get the infamous flashing cursor on a black screen. I can access the terminal by doing Ctrl + Alt + F2, and everything seems OK, it just will not load the main OS.

I tried so many solutions online, but I think I have narrowed down my problem to something very specific. After reinstalling Nvidia drivers multiple times, I tried to run `nvidia-settings` and now get the error messages;

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_glib_script_to_scrip
libinvidia-gtk3.so: cannot open the shared object file: No such file or directory
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_glib_script_to_script
libinvidia-gtk2.so: cannot open the shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now this is the same error message I got when trying to open an image earlier, so narrows down further it is a graphics issue. However, after some googling, it seems the package `libharfbuzz` has something to do with this `hb_glib_script_to_script` business.

Here is where I might have made a mistake: I remember trying to reinstall/install a package called `libharfbuzz`, but I can't remember the reason. I downloaded a tar.gz of this package, and did the `./configure` and `sudo make install`. After whatever I did there a couple of weeks ago, I left it, and nothing bad has happened since then.

Some things I have tried:

- reinstalling all drivers
- loading the old kernel in GRUB
- changing GRUB settings including using `nomodeset`
- reinstalling `libpango-1.0-0` and `libharfbuzzb0` packages using `apt install`

Currently Ubuntu is unusable for me. Please help if you can. I am happy to provide more info if it is needed.

Comment: I read ```hb_glib_script_to_script``` is implemented by ```libharfbuzz0b``` (is libharfbuzzb0 a typing error in your post? If not, did you try to reinstall the correct package?). Since you installed another version of ```libharfbuzz``` with make install you should uninstall it with ```sudo make uninstall```. I believe this manually installed package is not managed by apt and can lead to problems (different versions on your systems...). You may want to check in ```/usr/local/lib``` and in ```/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu``` if you have many versions of ```libharfbuzz```

Comment: Also can you add the output of ```ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0``` ?

Comment: @UnderTheHoud the `sudo make uninstall` in the extracted tar.gz did the trick. That was so simple! Thanks so much for the help, such a simple solution

Comment: Nice to hear. I'll put this as an answer, such that you can accept it to close the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it is possible that having different versions of the same package leads to problems. Uninstall `libharfbuzz` that was installed with `sudo make install` by running `sudo make uninstall` in the extracted tar.gz